# Passing a string from a child activity using the back button

Tags: android-intent

First, I want to apologize, I've found lots of answers similar to this question, but I still cannot get my code to work properly.  I want to pass a string back to the parent activity after pressing the back button and then display that information in an edittext.

code:

(from parent activity)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Intent i = new Intent(ComputeActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("num1", editText1.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("num2", editText2.getText().toString());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
}); 
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (data == null) {
        return;
      }
        result = data.getExtras().getString("string_result");

      editTextResult.setText(result);
   }
```

(from child activity)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  super.onBackPressed();
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("string_result", result);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  finish();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!!! , try this:

In your First Activity :

```
//To get ArrayList of ImagePath to Gallery_MainActivity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 300 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){

          if(data.getStringArrayListExtra("galleryToValidar") !=null)
          {
              this.imagePath=data.getStringArrayListExtra("galleryToValidar");
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "[ "+data.getStringArrayListExtra("galleryToValidar").size()+" ]:Imagenes guardadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();
          }

    else
        {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No hay imagenes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();
        }

    }
 }
```

In the Second Activity:

/**
     * Pass Intent with back button
     */

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    if(imagePath.size()!=0)
    {

        for(int i=0; i<imagePath.size(); i++){
            auxImage.add(imagePath.get(i));
        }
    }

    Intent myImage = new Intent();
    myImage.putStringArrayListExtra("galleryToValidar",auxImage);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,myImage);

    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

This code works perfectly, good luck!!!